# Removing the floating part from Ids list

Tags: coldfusion

I have list in format

```
"4186.0,7573.0,4300.0,9479.0,9488.0,10642.0,7987.0,9480.0 "
```

Is there any function in coldfusion available, which removes all `".0"` from numbers in one go?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it always present - and always `.0`? Also out of curiosity, what is the use case? Just wondering if there are other options..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map()` from the [UnderscoreCF](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) library to gracefully solve this problem (in CF 10 or Railo 4).

```
_ = new Underscore();

listOfNums = "4186.0,7573.0,4300.0,9479.0,9488.0,10642.0,7987.0,9480.0 ";

arrayOfNums = _.map(listOfNums, function(num){
  return round(num);
});

result = arrayToList(arrayOfNums);
```

`map()` produces a new array of values by mapping each value in the collection through a transformation function. This allows you to have more control over the results.

Note: I wrote UnderscoreCF.

Comment: Totally voting this up for being the coolest way to solve the problem. Maybe not the most practical for something this simplistic, but way cool!

Comment: I agree that it is overkill, but yeah, neat way of applying a function to each element without coding a loop. `<cfloop list = "listOfNums" index = "i"><cfset listAppend(newNums,int(i))></cfloop>` is still more suited for this solution IMHO (and it is very H).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a simple function to do this, but there are a number of things you can do.

You can loop through the list and `numberFormat()` each item, placing it back in the list or creating a new list. This is inefficient, both in processing and in programming.

Because your list is just a string, you can replace the decimal part of your numbers with a simple string replace: `replace("123.0,456.0", ".0", "", "ALL")`. If your list ever grows different decimal digits other than ".0", you can upgrade that replace function to a regular expression to catch patterns of numbers.

Comment: I posted as an answer but as it only expounds on this idea, so i'm trying to delete it, the reReplace would look like `<cfset listOfNums = "4186.0,7573.540,4300.434,9479.0,9488.0,10642.0,7987.0,9480.0">
    <cfset listOfNums = reReplace(listOfNums, "\.[0-9]*", "", "all")>` Result is: `4186,7573,4300,9479,9488,10642,7987,9480`

Comment: @Travis - The reReplace approach seems more powerful than the replace approach. It should have been kept as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I usually use INT to drop the decimal of a number like barnyr suggested but if you wanted to treat it as a single string and not a list you could use reReplace (to elaborate on Nathan Strutz's idea) and do something like:

```
<cfset listOfNums = "4186.0,7573.540,4300.434,9479.,9488.0,10642.0,7987.0,9480.0">
<cfset listOfNums = reReplace(listOfNums, "\.[0-9]*", "", "all")>
```

Result is: `4186,7573,4300,9479,9488,10642,7987,9480`

it also removes the decimal point even if no numbers follow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Int() (equivalent of the floor() function in most other languages) function may be what you want: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f89.html

You'll still need to iterate over the list, applying the Int() function though.

Comment: You could do it implicitly casting to an `int[]` array then back to list ie `arrayToList(javacast("int[]", listToArray(list))`. But that is a lot of conversions ..